# php does not load css updates (with php and XAMPP)

Tags: php, html, css, visual-studio-code, xampp

I have 8 php files in the folder for a website, and a styles.css that is included. At the beginning everything worked perfectly but now the website doesn't change when I change something in CSS. However, the site still uses what was already in the same css document. even if i kick the styles.css out of the folder, the styles are still loaded. Only when I remove the link in the html head (even if the link does not lead to a file when I remove it as a test) are the styles no longer applied.

I use VS Code, Chrome and XAMPP

Comment: Sounds like you got a run-of-the-mill caching problem. Use [ctrl]+[f5] to force a reload that circumvents the cache (or whatever the equivalent might be for your browser/system), or keep your browser dev tools open with the "Disable cache" option activated on the network panel.

Comment: Your browser might cache the CSS file. Use a "hard refresh" (Ctrl+F5 in most browsers) to force it to re-download a copy from the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

In the `head` tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>" >
```

This will reload the css everytime the page loads.